# Typescript React/Redux : Argument of type 'typeof MyClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new to Redux and new to Typescript.

I've found a fairly good basic cut-down version of what I'm trying to do in [the react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md).

The code is like this :

```
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/index'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class TodoApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>test!</div>)
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch) }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

Both my code editor (VS Code with the TSLint extension) and `tsc` highlight that final `(TodoApp)` as an error, and this is the message I get :

> src/components/test.tsx(20,61): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof
>   TodoApp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{
>   todos: any; } & { actions: typeof "(filepath)...'.   Type 'typeof
>   TodoApp' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ todos: any; }
>   & { actions: typeof "(filepath)...'.
>       Type 'typeof TodoApp' provides no match for the signature '(props: { todos: any; } & { actions: typeof "(filepath)/actions/index"; } & {
>   children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement | null'.
>
> 20 export default connect(mapStateToProps,
>   mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)

My problem is that I don't entirely understand exactly what `mapStateToProps` and `connect` are doing, but prior to getting that understanding,
 **I'd like to know if there is a code change I can make here to fix this Typescript "error".**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your react component expects no props, so your `connect` has an error as it infers that `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` should both return empty objects

You can get around this by adding type defs for the react props, but there is also a lot of unsafe use of implicit `any`. If you were to fully type this application for safety's sake it would look something like this ....

```
interface ITodo {
  description: string
}

interface ITodosState {
  todos: ITodo[]
}

interface ITodoProps {
  todos: ITodo[]
}

interface ITodoActionProps {
  someAction: () => void
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component<ITodoProps & ITodoActionProps> {
    render() {
        return (<div>test!</div>)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: ITodosState): ITodoProps {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<ITodosState>): ITodoActionProps {
  return bindActionCreators({ someAction: actionCreators.someAction }, dispatch)
}

export default connect<ITodoProps, ITodoActionProps, {}>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

Comment: My actual working example was not quite the same as what I posted above, and my solution was actually changing `interface ITodoActionProps {
  someAction: () => void
}` to `interface ITodoActionProps {
  someAction: typeof actionCreators.someAction
}`

Your great answer made that clear right away - thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You haven't typed `TodoApp`'s props.

```
type Props = {
    todos: any[] // What ever the type of state.todos is
    actions: {
       addTodo: Dispatch<any>
    }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div>test!</div>
  }
}
```